# Return 1 or 0 on the basis of column value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want a procedure where I want to check one condition which is as below

> I have to check two columns of a table where if any one of the columns has value then return 1 otherwise return 0

Here is my table with query below

`SELECT BOCID, BUILDING_RJID FROM R4G_OSP.OTHER_FACILITY;`

**NOTE** I will pass two parameters to the procedure.

**UPDATE**

Tried like this, but dont know how to return it for 1 or 0

```
PROCEDURE GETVAL_BY_PARAMETER
   (
    P_BOCID NVARCHAR2,
   P_BUILDINGID NVARCHAR2,
    P_FLAG OUT NVARCHAR2
 )
   AS
    BEGIN 
    SELECT BOCID, BUILDING_RJID FROM R4G_OSP.OTHER_FACILITY
       where BOCID = P_BOCID or  BUILDING_RJID = P_BUILDINGID;
```

Comment: First of all, if it's Oracle it's not MySQL, please remove unrelated tags. Then, do you actually need it to be done with a procedure? Because it can be easily accomplished with a simple query.

Comment: @StefanoZanini: can u tell me the query and how to pass it. Please. removed the unwanted tags

Comment: You need to create a [function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php) to return a value.

Comment: @Nitish You can also return values from procedures using an `OUT` paramenter.

Comment: @MT0 Of course, its possible. But for these kinds of requirements(like `true` or `false`) `FUNCTION` should be the logical choice. I shouldn't have written 'need ' in my previous comment.

Comment: Try to look at functions like DECODE !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
PROCEDURE GETVAL_BY_PARAMETER
(
  P_BOCID NVARCHAR2,
  P_BUILDINGID NVARCHAR2,
  P_FLAG OUT NVARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN 
  SELECT 1
  INTO   P_FLAG
  FROM   R4G_OSP.OTHER_FACILITY
  WHERE  (  BOCID         = P_BOCID
         OR BUILDING_RJID = P_BUILDINGID )
  AND    ROWNUM = 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    P_FLAG := 0; -- Handle the case when neither parameter exists in the table.
END;
/
```

The `WHERE` clause will only match when the rows have a value (since `NULL` is never equal to any other value, even another `NULL`).

Comment: hi MTO are you their ?

Comment: do let me know once you back, there is slight change in my requirement